# How can I show offline maps? download completed successfully but how to display in offline mode using async storage in react native

Tags: react-native

I am going to develop an application by using third-party library called react-native-map-box. Currently, everything just working fine with online map as this third-party library is used map_box maps. But my problem is went I move to offline mode it would be caused a problem for my application.

My question is there any possible way to view downloaded maps using createPack method ex like offline region
application is load with the specific bound area of a country?